# Pod install taking a very long time

Tags: cocoapods

I'm running pod install on terminal for the first time and it's been taking a very long time (longer than 20 minutes). When i ran pod install --verbose it's getting stuck on this. Not sure if it should be taking this long, any ideas on how to fix it? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaTBx.png)

// Podfile

```
use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'UberEATS' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

Comment: Might be an old version of CocoaPods. What does `pod --version` say?

Comment: my pod version is 1.9.3

Comment: 1.9.3 shouldn't need to download the spec repo. Something in the Podfile is likely overriding the default cdn.

Comment: That's unusual. I pulled this project from github and the readme said "Pods are not pushed to this remote so you have to run the following before running the app: pod install". I'll edit the post to include what's written in the Podfile

Answer (score 0):

Delete `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` from the Podfile.

Recent versions of CocoaPods use a much faster cdn as the default source location.